# How does Facebook determine what the Top News is?

Tags: facebook, news-feed

Anyone know what algorithm Facebook uses to determine what to show me as Top News in the News Feed?  Many times I see items there that are quite old, and not particularly interesting.  Is there any way to help Facebook (via Like, for instance) determine what is Top News from my perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Facebook Help Center

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16162

> **How does the News Feed determine which content is most interesting?**
>
> The News Feed algorithm bases this on
> a few factors: how many friends are
> commenting on a certain piece of
> content, who posted the content, and
> what type of content it is (e.g.
> photo, video, or status update).

Generally interacting with the item tends to do trick for me (I maybe wrong have not tried against a large set of test cases). Try liking and commenting on the same item from your recent feed and see if gets bumped to the Top News Section.